# Pandas tz_localize daylight savings time problem

Tags: python, pandas, timezone-offset

I am working with a dataset that has dates that range from the late 1800's to 2020 and has the times in Pacific Standard Time (PST) regardless of Daylight Savings Time (DST) and prior to the late 1910's there was no DST. When localizing the datetimeindex in a pandas dataframe, is there a way to disregard the DST time change? I just want every time to have UTC-8:00.

Thank you in advance.